# CORS blocked on some directories, but not others

Tags: ajax, drupal, xmlhttprequest, cors

A week ago, I encountered a CORS error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at [domainA/example/directory/file.xml] from origin [domainB] has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I solved this by editing .htaccess, adding:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch ".+">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

This worked! However, I am now encountering the same problem when requesting data at the same domain, at a different path (i.e. "domainA/different/example/directory/file.json").

Shouldn't I be able to request any file, in any directory, based on the edits I made to .htaccess? (located at "/.../.../www/[domainA-root]/.htaccess")

It's worth noting that in my first example, [domainA/example/directory/file.xml] is a XML view created by Drupal, and is not a static file in an actual directory.

Comment: For the request for the file at the different path, what’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than 200 OK success response?

Comment: No status code returned. Just says '(failed)' in the status column.

Comment: For the request for the file at the different path, what happens if you try to open the URL for that directly in your browser?

Comment: It shows the JSON as plain text, as it would if you opened any JavaScript or JSON file in your browser.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message from the browsers console pane (in the web debugger)? Probably you are sending a header that is not allowed.

Comment: That is the exact message I’m getting on the console. I just replaced the domain names. I’m using jQuery AJAX with no added headers.

Answer (score -1):

rather than trying .+ in filematch, you should try:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(htm|html|css|js|php|json)$">
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
DefaultLanguage en-US
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "*"
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score -2):

That looks like the typical case in which your browser is caching the response of a previous OPTIONS request to specific URLs requested previously, the header was not there before and the browser won't bother to check again until the TTL expires.

I would say: check it the headers are there doing a verbose curl request from your command line, I.e.

```
curl -v https://yourhost/yourURL
```

Then you can take it from there